# Why depth test does not work in offscreen rendering for color pick?

Tags: java, opengl, off-screen, depth-testing

I'm using coloring and off-screen rendering to implement a selection tool for QUADS on OpenGL. But the depth test seems to not work in the off-screen rendering and at certain angles and rotations, the QUAD behind the front one is selected. Any thoughts on how I should set up my Buffers and/or attachments?
Does this problem have anything to do with my normals??? Or is just depth test?? I personally think it's depth test, I just can't get the damn thing working!!!

Here is My init function for buffers:

```
public void init(final GL2 gl) {
    // setup
    gl.glGenFramebuffers(frameBufferIds.capacity(), frameBufferIds);
    gl.glGenRenderbuffers(renderBufferIds.capacity(), renderBufferIds);
    gl.glBindRenderbuffer(GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferIds.get(0));
    // 
    ViewPort viewPort = ViewPort.getCurrent(gl);
    gl.glRenderbufferStorage(GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL2.GL_RGBA, viewPort.getWidth(), viewPort.getHeight());

    /**
     * Comment 1
     */
    //  gl.glRenderbufferStorage(GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, viewPort.getWidth(), viewPort.getHeight());
    
    // attach the render buffer to color attachment point
    gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferIds.get(0));
    gl.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferIds.get(0));
    /**
     * Comment 2
     */
    // gl.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferIds.get(0));
    //
    if (gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        System.out.println("Render Buffer problem!");
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the "Comment 1" and "Comment 2" parts, I get a render buffer problem. But I've heard that I should attach "a render buffer to the GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT in addition to the color attachment." (Source: [Look at this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751081/how-to-use-depth-testing-when-rendering-to-an-offscreen-buffer-then-onto-texture). I wonder How can I do that.

Also, here is my usage code:

```
gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DITHER);

// 1. render in offscreen
init(gl);
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
offscreenRender(gl, selectionType);

// 2. read pixel
gl.glReadBuffer(GL2.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT);
gl.glReadBuffer(GL2.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

gl.glReadPixels((int) (pos.x - pickWidth / 2), (int) (viewPort.getHeight() - pos.y - pickWidth / 2), pickWidth, pickWidth,  GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_FLOAT, pointSelectionPixels);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read couple of hours about frame and render buffers all over the internet. Finally I find my problem on this [site](http://wanochoi.com/?p=116). This site says we must render the color into the **Texture** and the depth into the **RenderBuffer**. That's the point!

And after setup the buffers and texture, everything is prepared for reading depth and color value with `glReadPixels` method.

```
// reading color
glReadBuffer( GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT );
glReadPixels( 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, color );

// reading depth
glReadBuffer( GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT );
glReadPixels( 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, depth );
```

Thank you [Wano Choi](http://wanochoi.com/?author=1)! :D

Answer (score 2):

Of course the depth test doesn't work; you didn't *create a depth buffer*. FBOs do not intrinsically have a depth buffer, just as they don't intrinsically have a color buffer. If you want both, you must create *both*.

So create a renderbuffer using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`, or [another appropriate depth format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Depth_formats), and attach that to the `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` of the FBO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I did that on "Comment 1" and "Comment 2" part and it doesn't work!